# ¿Como redireccion una ventana de .aspx con una llamada ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirección

Como hago la redireccion de mi ventana actual a una nueva a travez de una llamada ajax.

Codigo de la llamada ajax:

```
function autenticarme() {
    var nick = $(".txtNick").val(); 
    var pass = $(".txtPass").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.aspx/conectarBD",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        data: "{ nick: '" + nick + "',password: '" + pass + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            window.location = data."http://localhost:52403/WebSite2/CRUD.aspx";
        }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Ya use los siguientes metodos dentro de succes:

```
   location.replace("CRUD.aspx");
   window.location.href = 'CRUD.aspx';
    window.location.assign("CRUD.aspx");
    window.open('@Url.Action("CRUD", "ReportExecution")');
```

Ninguno me realiza alguna accion solo que la pagina en la que estoy no se moviliza.

> Actualizacion

Con esta linea de codigo en succes ya me redirecciona:

```
window.open('CRUD.aspx')
```

Pero me abre la ventana en una nueva pestaña, me gustaria saber como cierro la ventana actual si una nueva se abre.

Comment: Has visto si te arroja un error en la consola al usar: `location.href = 'CRUD.aspx';`

Comment: @Davlio no me marca ningun error en la consola

Comment: Por descarte, hace un redireccionamiento al usar `location.href = 'https://www.google.com';`.

Comment: @Davlio sigue sin redireccionar a google

Comment: @David, he leído varias veces la pregunta, pero creo que esto te puede ayudar: si necesitas cerrar la ventana actual, puedes usar lo que dice [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29855792/4092887) o [esta respuesta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076307/4092887). Luego tu dices: `Pero me abre la ventana en una nueva pestaña` = ¿necesitas abrir una nueva ventana o nueva pestaña y qué pasa con la ventana "anterior"?

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave no quiero abrir nuevas ventanas solo quiero que en la misma pestaña me redireccione a la ventana de CRUD.aspx y gracias leere el link que comentaste

Comment: @David, con gusto. Para redireccionar desde tu ventana, puedes mirar esta [respuesta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/4092887) o buscar: `window.location.href javascript redirect`. Espero que, una vez encuentres la solución, te recomiendo publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en el success de la llamada Ajax, el redireccionamiento se hace [asi](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp).

```
function autenticarme() {
    var nick = $(".txtNick").val(); 
    var pass = $(".txtPass").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.aspx/conectarBD",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        data: "{ nick: '" + nick + "',password: '" + pass + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            location.href = "http://localhost:52403/WebSite2/CRUD.aspx";
        }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Ejemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp